# Is there any known reason for Dean's actions at the end of Season 10?

Tags: supernatural

In Supernatural "Season 10 Episode 23 - Brother's Keeper" Dean

> kills Death

for like no reason I know of. Can someone explain to me what his reasoning for this was?

Comment: given that this happens within the last 10 minutes of the season finale, I dunno that we have a good answer yet. Maybe he just missed?

Comment: so your saying there IS no reason for why he did it? At least not yet?

Comment: Death would have forced the issue regarding the unleashing of "the darkness." He doesn't want the universe to end anymore than anyone else. He was content when the Winchesters appeared to be working with him but Dean knew that Death would not just accept them reneging on the deal.

Comment: Death's condition for helping Dean was that he had to kill Sam. After Dean agreed to that there was no way Death was going to let him change his mind or back out; he'd been burned by the Winchesters before. So Dean's options were killing Death (and when would he have a better chance than when handed Death's own scythe?) or kill his brother, and it seems he chose Sam (as he always does).

Comment: Well, I'm sure in-uinverse he had a reason, I'm saying we don't know it yet. I have a *guess* why he might have done it but certainly nothing concrete.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist except that Dean could just have refused Death's help and kept the Mark -- which he ended up doing anyway. All Death was concerned about was that *someone* had the Mark on them, he didn't seem particularly bothered by who. So killing Death was pointless.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Making deals that they almost immediately regret, and which force them to make even worse decisions to back out of them, is kind of the Winchester way though.

Comment: I know that different people have different approaches to spoilers, @MikeEdenfield, but don't you think that wrapping two words in spoiler text is a bit unnecessary when those same two words remain in the title?  :P

Comment: yeah I missed the title, sorry.

Comment: The question is also based on the assumption that he DID indeed kill Death, which we don't know yet to be true. All we know for sure is that he betrayed Death. In fact, I imagine the reality of what he did and what consequences it will have are a huge plot point of the next season.

Comment: can you really kill Death?

Answer (score 2):

If Dean hadn't killed Death, one way or another, this would have resulted in Sam's death, since Death would have done the deed if Dean was unable to. Also, there wasn't the option of just letting them both go, as Death would most definitely have been concerned about the release of the Darkness. The other option was transferring the Mark to someone else, but Dean wouldn't do this, and it didn't seem as if Death was going to force him. So Dean's only logical option was to kill Death, lest Sam died.

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking that Death knew that "HIS" death would be a key thing to help Sam and Dean in the upcoming trials they will face. While death and the boys are not "friends" by any means... Death has always had a soft spot for them and usually helps them on what they are need to do, not what they are trying to do.

Answer (score -6):

Cain himself told the real story behind all that Cain and Abel stuff, to Dean.

He did kill his brother - he became Lucifer's sort of 'pet-thing', (essentially what Sam was transitioning to some series ago) so his soul can go to heaven. This is as an exchange for the brotherkiller's (Dean in the current case) soul going to hell, he become the knigh in service of evil.

The thing was that he had to kill his brother *himself*. So Dean was really intending to kill Sam, hoping that his soul will go to heaven, if he kills him, and end the apocalypse or whatever was going on.

Unfortunately Crowley didn't have time or didn't wnat to tell him about the burden of all this. As it was said that evil and darkness come to the eden with the mark of Cain, or were kind of freed, kind of locked in the mark of Cain.